# Progressbar not showing current progress

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have a `WebView` where I am using a Horizontal `ProgressBar`. I have applied a code to show its progress, but it is not working. Here is the code.

```
    mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.pb);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress){
            // Update the progress bar with page loading progress
            int prog = mProgressBar.getProgress();
            mProgressBar.setProgress(prog);
            if(newProgress == 100){
                // Hide the progressbar
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) 
        {
            // Visible the progressbar
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            finalMySwipeRefreshLayout1.setRefreshing(false);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

I have used `mProgressBar.setProgress(prog);` in above code. Then why it is not working? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your are setting the progress bar wrongly , you should use `webchromeClient` , and set the `progressBar` with `newProgress`, here how to do it :

```
   mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress){
        // Update the progress bar with page loading progress
        mProgressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
        if(newProgress == 100){
            // Hide the progressbar
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Could You explain why should I use webChromeClient?

Comment: Using WebChromeClient allows you to handle Javascript dialogs, favicons, titles, and the progress.